# Why in a Binary Search do we Divide by 2 and not some other higher constant

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory, binary-search, theory

for example, why don't we do `n/3` instead of `n/2`

### Some Maths

The recurrence relation for a binary search using `n/2` is

`T(n) = T(n/2) + C` 
which can be simplified to

`log2(m) = n`

and `n/3`

`T(n) = T(n/3) + C` 
which can be simplified to

`log3(m) = n`

so my question is: **since `log3(m) < log2(m)` why do we use `n/2`**

Comment: What exactly are you referring to by "binary search"? For roots? For elements? What's T? On the other hand, consider what we actually want to minimize.

Comment: Eg from Wikipedia 'ternary search': T(n) = T(2n/3) + 1 = Θ(log ⁡n). It would be helpul if you would give the argument that you refer to but do not explain via "since". Please also google many clear, concise, specific versions of your question before you post. Eg googling your title gives [Divide and Conquer algorithms – Why not split in more parts than two?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/197107).

Comment: @philipxy `T(n)=` is to show that we are dealing with a recurrence relation; well as a binary search should be the same algorithm for all of those, I don't think it's necessary to specify; I'm coming from a theoretical standpoint, not a practical one. Useful link tho.

Comment: "is to show that..." does not say what T is. Neither does calling it "The recurrence relation". It is some function of an algorithm and a number--what? The point of my first comment (& my comment about "since") is that you are suggesting an n that makes T(n) smaller--but so what? What we want to minizmize is something else. I am trying to get you to think & write more clearly both for answerers & for you as answerer. And it certainly does matter what you are searching for, eg roots vs elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that Ternary search has fewer recursive calls than Binary search `(log3(m) < log2(m))` however Ternary search has more comparisons in the worst case than Binary search.

To examine a bit more let's compare Binary and Ternary search algorithms in C++

**Binary Search**

```
// A recursive binary search function. It returns location of x in
// given array arr[l..r] is present, otherwise -1
int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
   if (r >= l)
   {
      int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

      // If the element is present at the middle itself
      if (arr[mid] == x)  return mid;

      // If element is smaller than mid, then it can only be present
      // in left subarray
      if (arr[mid] > x) return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

      // Else the element can only be present in right subarray
      return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
   }

   // We reach here when element is not present in array
   return -1;
 }
```

**Ternary Search**

```
// A recursive ternary search function. It returns location of x in
// given array arr[l..r] is present, otherwise -1
int ternarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
   if (r >= l)
   {
        int mid1 = l + (r - l)/3;
        int mid2 = mid1 + (r - l)/3;

        // If x is present at the mid1
        if (arr[mid1] == x)  return mid1;

        // If x is present at the mid2
        if (arr[mid2] == x)  return mid2;

        // If x is present in left one-third
        if (arr[mid1] > x) return ternarySearch(arr, l, mid1-1, x);

        // If x is present in right one-third
        if (arr[mid2] < x) return ternarySearch(arr, mid2+1, r, x);

        // If x is present in middle one-third
        return ternarySearch(arr, mid1+1, mid2-1, x);
   }
   // We reach here when element is not present in array
   return -1;
}
```

In the worst case, Binary search does `2log2(n) + 1` comparisons where Ternary search does `4log3(n) + 1` comparisons

The comparisons boil down to `log2(n)` and `2log3(n)`

Changing bases, `2log3(n) = (2 / log2(3)) * log2(n)`

Since `(2 / log2(3)) > 1` Ternay search does more comparisons in the worst case

[Source](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-preferred-ternary-search/)

Comment: If the length of the input is huge, then the ternary search would have more advantage and faster than the binary search